# input from user using for loop and prompt dialogue box shows different behaviour

Tags: java, android, for-loop, user-input, android-alertdialog

i used the code below to get user input in android app. it runs fine but what i found after several attempts is that.
the method below is called from a for loop to get different values.

1. The code takes input in reverse order i.e it has to take value for x and then y. while on the app i am asked to enter value of y and then x.
2. it doesnot wait for the user input it shows the dialogue box but keeps on running the whole program. as when i enter any value doesnt make any changes as it has to do.

what i believe is that the reverse order of dialogue boxes is also from the same reason that the second dialogue box overlaps the first one.

how do i make it stop unless user enter any data and then move forward?
also when i remove final from the editbox in the code, it gives error the please use remove view because this child already has a parent etc.

code is provided below

```
void var_init(String to_match,String[][] temp) {

    String t_match=to_match;
//problem in the below line


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RuleEngine.this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter Value for"+t_match);

// Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(RuleEngine.this);

    builder.setView(input);

// Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           t_replace = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its becasue the dialogue boxes overlaps each other with every iteration. in reality the x is coming first but overlapped by the y dialogue box. an as async behaviour try to find other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method from your **OnClick** methods of *positive* or *negative* button 
i.e 
when the user presses *ok* or *cancel* button, then check your condition to show another dialog or not and call the function which is generating the dialog.