# Can we make a for loop to get user input in every iteration before moving to next iteration in android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, user-input

is it possible to iterate for loop step wise such that i get value using prompt dialogue box or editbox before moving to next iteration.

```
for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
{
string variable_ = userinput //wait unless user enter someting before moving to next iteration i.e x=1.
}
```

i know in Java we can use simple scanner to do this but in android, i used propmtdialogue box as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403552/input-from-user-using-for-loop-and-prompt-dialogue-box-shows-different-behaviour)  but it just moves along without waiting.

Comment: Cant you use a simple method that gives a dialog box and runs until the desired result is reached?

Comment: actually i have a for loop which calls this method, n within this method a dialogue box is prompted to ask user for input. the dialogue box appears but the code down to end is also run without waiting for the input from the user. u can see the code in the link provided in the question

Comment: Yeah i can understand what happens. But i mean whether you can choose to use another method INSTEAD of the for loop? Ex:- you have a value like n=0; you ask the user something. User responds. You increment the value and call the same function. You keep doing this unit n<10 is reached.

Answer (score 1):

One way is possible

```
//create one boolean variable
   boolean inputCame ;
for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
{
  inputCame = false; // make it false before reading input
string variable_ = userinput //wait unless user enter someting before moving to next iteration i.e x=1.

   // set inputCame variable true  when your ok and cancel button of dialogue is pressed

   while(inputCame==false){ // stop the for loop until inputCame is true

   }

}
```

This is just an example to achieve it.

**EDIT**

I see you are using `AlertDialog` . `AlertDialog` is  asynchronous, it doesn't stop further code execution.

There are lots of example given on google about your question.

One I can see over here 
http://www.tomswebdesign.net/Articles/Android/wait-for-user-input-from-dialog.html

Comment: this is putting the app into infinite loop? as within while loop the inputcame  will remain same...i tried it but black screen for long and no result.

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan Ohh.. I see you are using AlertDialog . AlertDialog is asynchronous, it doesn't stop further code execution. You have to look for other solution

Answer (score 0):

You cant as you cant and should not block the main thread. For what you want you will need to implement your own observer pattern over your input dialog.